# SQL: comparing string against column and column against column based on results of first compare

Tags: sql, string, oracle, compare

I have these columns:

```
ID, Last_Name, First, Email, Email type
```

E-mail types are PERS and WORK
A person can have both a PERS and a WORK e-mail address.
the work address contains Last_Name within the e-mail address.

Example:

```
14569, Smith, Joe, money133@aol.com, PERS
14569, Smith, Joe, JSmith142@company.com, WORK
59876, Conway, Mary, MConway131@company.com, PERS
59876, Conway, Mary, MConway131@company.com, WORK
79654, Far, John, JohnFar@company.com, PERS
79654, Far, John, JFar241@company.com, WORK
```

Here is what I am trying to do:
I am searching for people who have their work e-mail listed in their personal e-mail field.
The e-mail field may contain either work or personal e-mail addresses.
If the e-mail type = PERS  and it contains 'my.company.com', I want to then look at the PERS e-mail address to see if it does NOT contain Last_Name.

The results should be both the incorrect pers e-mail and the correct work e-mail:

```
79654, Far, John, JohnFar@company.com, PERS
79654, Far, John, JFar241@company.com, WORK

SELECT 
ID, pp.Last_Name, pp.First, em.Email, em.Email_type
from Somewhere pp
join emailarea em
on id.somewhere_ID = em.email_ID
where
(em.email_type = 'PERS' or em.email_type = 'WORK')
and
(em.email_type = 'PERS' and em.email like '%my.company.com')
and 
em.email not like Last_Name
```

How do I compare the em.email to the Last_Name?
Also, since i say it must be PERS, it will not show me any WORK e-mail addresses.  I need help with that problem too. 
The results are:

```
14569, Smith, Joe, money133@aol.com, PERS
59876, Conway, Mary, MConway131@company.com, PERS
79654, Far, John, JohnFar@company.com, PERS
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Since the work email is supposed to contain the last name, shouldn't it be looking at that one to see if it doesn't contain the last name, not the personal email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join with the `emailarea` table twice, once for the personal email, and then for the work email, so you can return both of them.

```
SELECT somewhere_ID, pp.Last_Name, pp.First, emw.email AS Work_Email, emp.email AS Pers_Email
FROM somewhere pp
JOIN emailarea emp ON emp.email_ID = pp.somewhere_ID
JOIN emailarea emw ON emw.email_ID = pp.somewhere_ID
WHERE emp.type = "PERS"
AND emw.type = "WORK"
AND emp.email LIKE '%my.company.com'
AND emp.email NOT LIKE '%' || pp.Last_Name || '%'
```

Comment: I am in Oracle.
Sometimes a person may *think* they are putting their work e-mail address in their personal e-mail address field, but they are wrong.  I am trying to find when people enter the wrong company e-mail address in as their personal.  I hope that makes sense!

Comment: Isn't that backwards? Their work email should be in the WORK field, not the PERS field, shouldn't it?

Comment: Yes, but they can still use their work e-mail as their personal.  I'm sorry this is confusing. :(  
 I guess it would be easier to compare PERS to WORK *if* the PERS contains 'my.company.com' in the address.  IN this case, it would not matter if the address contained the Last_Name!
So:  select ----where emailtype=PERS and like 'my.company'
Then compare the PERS emails that contain 'my.company' to the WORK e-mails to find those that do not match.  ::scratches head::

Comment: If you want to compare the work and personal emails, you can use the approach in my answer. Just add something like `AND emp.email = emw.email` to test if they're the same. Whatever you want, both the personal and work emails are available in those two columns.

Comment: Basically, start with the first 5 lines of my query. Then add any other criteria you want on either or both email columns.

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That is it!!!!  I simply put in my *real* code:
    and pe.GOREMAL_EMAL_CODE = 'PERS' 
    and ca.GOREMAL_EMAL_CODE = 'WORK'
    AND pe.GOREMAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS like '%my.company'
    and pe.GOREMAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS <> ca.GOREMAL_EMAIL_ADDRESS